What will happen to Demon Kali?
Well, we know about demon Kali and while, I had found various medias says that Kali is going to be the nemesis of Kalki. But, AFAIK, Bhagavata Purana(for example) never mentioned about Kalki vs Kali.
However, i want a scriptural basis for it. So, my question is, What will happen to him during Kalki avatar and/or at least the end of a Kalpa?

Kalipurusha has never been considered the sort of evil entity as it is understood. This transformation of Kali being the Hindu equivalent of the Devil in Abrahamic religions is most likely the handiwork of ISKCON.

Kalki Purana says that Kali will be defeated by personifications of Satya Yuga and Dharma and will run away.

After the enemy had been routed, Dharma and Satya-yuga personified
entered Kalt’s capital, Visasana, and set the whole city ablaze by
releasing fiery arrows. Indeed, Kali was also burnt in the
conflagration, but he managed to survive. Because his sons and wives
were killed in the fire, Kali felt he had no alternative but to
renounce his kingdom. He left the city alone and traveled to another
country, while continually shedding tears out of distress.


Chapter 21, Kalki Purana.

